# Filter Netsuite Search Using Count of ID/Date Created

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have a Netsuite Search that looks for leads coming in and groups them by email. It then counts `ID` and `Date Created`.

This tells me if I have a duplicate in the system if either number is greater than 1.

My problem is I can't seem to find a way to limit my results to only those who have a `Count of ID/Date` greater than 1.

My end goal is to have the search email when a new record is created where the count is at least 2. Thus alerting me that duplicates are being created in the system.

This is where I figured out how to create my search.

http://blog.prolecto.com/2012/10/18/how-to-find-duplicates-in-netsuite/

Answer (score 1):

On the search page go to:

Criteria > Summary. And enter there:

- Summary Type: Count
- Field : ID/Date greater than 1

Set the Email alert with this box checked:

- Send Email Alerts When Records are Created/Updated